# reCAPTCHA not showing after page refresh

Tags: browser-cache, recaptcha

Why is google **reCaptcha2** (gReCaptcha) not showing after a page refresh,
 but showing if page is reopened by the link?

See this video for explanation: http://take.ms/I2a9Z
Page url: https://orlov.io/signup

**Page first open**: captcha exists.
**Navigate by link**: captcha exists.
**Open new browser tab**: captcha exists.
**Refreshing page by refresh icon, ctrl+R, ctrl+F5**: captcha **NOT** exists.

I added body unload event to prevent browser cache, it did not help.

Browsers for testing:
Firefix 39.0
Chome: 44.0.2403.125 m
Opera: 30.0

In all browsers I get the same result. So does this mean there's an error on my side?

Comment: Try turning off your cache. Maybe the Signup link is POSTing (which doesn't cache) or re-directing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the browser and the speed of your network. You are calling ReCaptcha with a callback, but you call it before you define the callback. Depending on your network speed or browser quirks, it might execute before the rest of the script has loaded.

Line 330:

```
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderReCaptchaCallback&amp;render=explicit&amp;hl=en-US" async defer></script>
```

Line 351:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if (typeof (renderReCaptchaCallback) === "undefined") {
    var reCaptchaWidgets = {};
    var renderReCaptchaCallback = function() {
        jQuery.each(reCaptchaWidgets, function(widgetId, widgetOptions) {
            grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById(widgetId), widgetOptions);
        });
    };
}</script>
```

So I would move the definition of `renderReCaptchaCallback` to the top of the page so it is defined well before trying to load it.

Comment: Yes! You're right! I move this widget code to HEAD and in works!